# Excel: SEQUENCE and dynamic arrays

Tags: excel

I want to do the following

```
A1: x
B1: y
A2=SEQUENCE(10)
B2=A2#^2
```

When I try to create a table for the range A1:B11, I get the table header x an y,
and in the first row below I get a #SPILL error.

Is there a way of using SEQUENCE in a table?

Comment: No, spilled arrays are not permitted within a table.

Comment: But the array is not spilled. I created a SEQUEN~CE an a further column based on the sequence, and when I trid to ruen this range into a table I got the spilled error.

Comment: I don't understand. In your example the array is spilled. Functions like `SEQUENCE` always spill an array.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand spilled. IMHO spilled indicated that the array a dynamic array formula like SEQUENCE creates would need space which is already in use by another formula (or data), which is not true in my example. I can create the formulas and values in columns A and B and I get a valid not spilled array. Only when I try to make the range a table, I get the SPILLED error.

Comment: Like I said, any formula which spills cannot be entered into an Excel table.